# ElasticSearch snapshot - AlreadyClosedException is already closed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of date-based indices, I'm trying to create a snapshot to load it at a different index.

Now, the indexes are monthly, all previous months succeed but the recent 2018-04 is active and failing when I'm trying to create a snapshot

```
{
  "index": "log-2018.04",
  "index_uuid": "log-2018.04",
  "shard_id": 0,
  "reason": "IndexShardSnapshotFailedException[Failed to snapshot]; nested: FlushFailedEngineException[Flush failed]; nested: AlreadyClosedException[translog [362] is already closed (path [/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/0XYh_UpATpK2lwX8vKgQVA/0/translog/translog-362.tlog]]; ",
  "node_id": "Cd3rZ3UsSFOmRYDC5cfdsg",
  "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting ElasticSearch solved the issue, weird.